# Ecore decorator

Tags: decorator, eclipse-emf

I have a generated Ecore model - works perfectly fine.

what I now do is, create an instance of the model programmatically and load it:

```
EARepository repository = EaadapterFactory.eINSTANCE.createEARepository();
repository.setFile(f);
repository.load();
```

Now I can call the methods like

```
repository.getName();
```

works fine!

My Problem: I want to customize the behavior of `getName()` now!. I would like to set a decorator here, like the genmodel does. E.g. the `getName()` method should return "no value set" if it has no value set.

Is it possible to customize the `getName()`'s behavior method here, like setting a decorator ?!

Reason: I want to keep the original behavior of the model. But in one of my use cases, the model should behave a little bit different.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should be using the generated item providers for producing the labels you see in the UI. I.e., there is a generated EARepositoryItemProvider with a getText method that you'd specialize for this purpose.